# How to import a class from a module from a package dynamically?

Tags: python, import, module

This is probably really simple, but I don't understand it. The following works:

#### foo.py

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

#### bar.py

```
module = __import__('foo')
foo = module.__dict__['Foo']
```

Afterwards, `foo` is the class `foo.Foo` as expected.

---

Yet, if I put `a.py` into a package, it stops working:

#### qux/__init__.py

(empty file)

#### qux/foo.py

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

#### bar.py

```
module = __import__('qux.foo')
foo = module.__dict__['Foo']
```

Running `python bar.py` gives me `KeyError: 'Foo'`, but the module import is still successful.

What's going on, and how do I get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to import a submodule, you can do something like this:

```
package = __import__('qux', fromlist=['foo'])
module = getattr(package, 'foo')
```

Note that with a `fromlist` the `__import__` returns the most nested name in the first parameter, so you could substitute `baz.bar.qux` in the `__import__` call to access the `baz.bar.qux.foo` module.

Comment: I'm sure this is very Pythonic and makes perfect sense to many people, but man is this convoluted to me. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3):

`__import__` applied to nested module names returns the toplevel module/package - which is `qux` here. All modules are, however, inserted into `sys.modules`, so you can simply lookup `qux.foo` in there.

See the PyDoc on `__import__()` -it's all described there.

Comment: Note that 'import qux.foo' works analogously -- `qux` ends up in the local namespace, but `foo` is only accessible as an attribute of `qux`.

Comment: Indeed, it suddenly and mysteriously appeared in the docs now that I look again: "When the name variable is of the form package.module, normally, the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, not  the module named by name. However, when a non-empty fromlist  argument is given, the module named by name is returned."

Answer (score 2):

You can directly access a module, nested or not, using `importlib`:

```
import importlib
module_name="qux.foo"
mod=importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

See http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fromlist parameter to reference a submodule:

```
temp = __import__('qux.foo', globals(), locals(), ['Foo'], -1)
foo = temp.Foo
```